# Show that the equation $y^2 = x^3 +xz^4$ has no solutions in nonzero integers $x,y,z$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that the equation $y^2 = x^3 +xz^4$ has no solutions in nonzero integers $x,y,z$.

There is given hint: Suppose that there is a solution. First show that it can be reduced to a solution satisfying $\gcd(x,z)=1$. Then use the fact that $x^3+ xz^4= x(x^2+z^4)$ is a perfect square to show that there are no solutions other than $x=y=0$.

The hint tells to prove by contradiction approach. So, $y\mid x,z\implies y\mid p$, where $p=(x,z)$. Hence, $\exists X,Z\in \mathbb{Z},\,x=Xp, z=Zp\implies y^2= X^3p^3 +XpZ^4p^4$
$\implies y^2= Xp^3(X^2+Z^4p^2)$.

---

Is it valid to conclude from the last line, any of the below two separate conclusions : 
1. The set of common divisors of $y^2, x^3, xz^4$ are the same; hence let $gcd(y^2, x^3, xz^4)=p'$

2.$\,\,p^3\mid y^2\implies \exists y=p^2Y, \,\,\,\,p^2\mid y$

Comment: I'd say a key first step is to remark that we can assume $x$ is square free (why?).

Comment: @lulu Please elaborate more.

Comment: Well, first establish the step in my hint (that's not difficult).  then remark that any prime which divides $x$ must divide $y^2$ only once, which is impossible (note that $p\, |\,x\implies p\,\nmid z$ since $\gcd(x,z)=1$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not much more than a lengthy remark, but it's worth posting as an answer, I think, because it shows that proving this is at least as hard as proving the strong version of Fermat's Last Theorem for $n=4$. That is, suppose that $a^4+b^4=c^2$ with $abc\not=0$. Then, letting $x=a^2$, $z=b$, and $y=ac$, we first have $x^2+z^4=c^2$, and thus $x(x^2+z^4)=xc^2=(ac)^2=y^2$ with $xyz=a^3cb\not=0$. So if $y^2=x^3+xz^4$ has no solutions with $xyz\not=0$, then $a^4+b^4=c^2$ has no solutions with $abc\not=0$ either.

Comment: Please elaborate it more. I am unable to comprehend it.

Comment: I request only one bit of information: as it is given that $y^2 = Xp^3 (X^2+Z^4p^2)$, leading to the implication that $p^3\mid y^2$. Can we certainly take that $p^2\mid y^2$, if so how? By 'how', I mean the logic behind such assumption.

Comment: Since $p^3|y^2$, then $y^2=kp^3=(kp)p^2$, hence $p^2|y^2$

Comment: @asdf But, I need the proof for the implication: $p^3\mid y^2\implies p^2\mid  y$. I am unable to use your approach in the above comment to get that: $p^2\mid y$, as can only get that $y^2= kp^2=(kp)p$, hence $p\mid y^2$ by following that approach. Sorry, the above comment of mine has typo, as the actual proof is accessible to me after the earlier comment (of mine), and till that was referring to a wrong source.

Comment: @jiten, it would help to know how you came across this problem. All I'm really saying here is the result you're trying to prove is stronger than the strong version of Fermat's Last Theorem for $n=4$, which is usually proved by the method of "infinite descent." If you're not familiar with that technique, you may want to put this problem on hold and come back to it later, when you've seen how infinite descent works.

Comment: It is the first problem in the 29th(30th) chapter of 3rd (4th) edn. of the text : A Friendly Introduction by Silverman. The chapter has title as $X^4+Y^4=Z^4$. I am sorry for not going through the text sequentially, as there is discussion of the infinite descent method earlier. I have read (not from this text, but in the first chapter of the  text by Watkins, on pg. #12, 13), approach of 'infinite descent' as used by Fermat. It is not interesting there, as no further examples are given. However, I request to tell why this problem is stronger version than the strong version of FLT for $n=4$.

Comment: @jiten, I'm presenting the connection in its contrapositive form: If $a^4+b^4=c^2$ has a nontrivial solution, then $y^2=x^3+xz^4$ has a nontrivial solution. Just turn that around, using the logical equivalence of $P\implies Q$ and $\lnot Q\implies \lnot P$.

Answer (score 1):

For starers, we must find $x,y,z$ all positive integers.

There are two possibilities : either $x$ is a square, say $x=A^2$ or otherwise $x=a^2b$ in which b is a square free integer.

Case 1. $y^2=A^2(A^4+z^4) \implies (y/A)^2 = Y^2 = A^4+z^4$ which is impossible due to the Fermat's LT (strong version for $n=4$).

Case 2. $y^2=a^2b(a^4b^2+z^4) \implies (y^2/a^2) = b(a^4b^2+z^4) \implies b|(a^4b^2+z^4) \implies b|z^4 \implies b|z$. So, $(y/ab)^2 = b(a^4+z_1^4b^2)$ in which $z=z_1b$. Again, $b|a^4$ which implies $b|a$. Thus, $(y/ab^2)^2 = (a_1^4b^3+z_1^4b) = b(a_1^4b^2+z_1^4)$ in which $a=a_1b$. So every time we find a new positive integer satisfying in the non-ending sequence $y>y_1=y/a>y_2=y/(ab)> \dots$ unless $a=1=b$ thus  $x=1$. But if $x=1$ $y^2=1+z^4$ has positive integer solutions contradicting the mentioned Fermat's Theorem.