# Implications based on the equality $y^2 = x^3 +xz^4$ for integers $x,y,z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If it is given that there are $3$ quantities, $x,y,z$ linked by the equality: $y^2 = x^3 +xz^4$ <del>leading to the implications:
 (i) y^2\mid x^3,
(ii)  y^2\mid xz^4.</del>

It is stated in the proof that: $p\mid y$ with $p=\gcd(x,z)$ i.e., $\exists X,Z\in \mathbb{Z},\,\,\, x=pX,z=pZ.$
Have two questions based on that : 
$A$. How can it be implied that $p^2\mid y$? This is given in the proof as in the link to my earlier post, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2702461/424260).
To repeat, my question is why $p^3\mid y^2 \implies p^2\mid y$, if the title equality is assumed true.

$B$. Can I 'further' imply that $y\mid x$? $\,\,$If so, how?

Comment: $8^2|4^3$ but $8$ doesn't divide $4$. Also, what is $p$?

Comment: @asdf I hope that the edit makes it clear about $p$, being the $\gcd$ of $x,z$. It is a part of proof by contradiction, as shown in the edited OP (see the last line), that this hypothesis is accepted. So, the example showing the failure is not tenable in this context.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your idea is - are you assuming that $A$ holds?

Comment: @asdf No, I just assume (as shown in the contradiction based proof, as linked in the last line of the edited OP) that the title equality holds. Rest all is following from that. Actually, the confusion arises from the proof by contradiction (as shown in the last line of the edited OP), that $B$ will certainly hold, as $p^3\mid y^2$.

Comment: @asdf sorry, very sorry. I am not too clear about implications (i), (ii). Anyway, these two were invented by me. I have deleted these in the edited post. The source proof refers to the main issue of $B$ being true as $p^3\mid y^2$, on assuming the title to be true, as part of the proof by contradiction, (as in the link in the last line of the edited OP). So, my question is why $p^2\mid y^3 \implies p^2\mid y$, if the title equality is assumed true.

Comment: @asdf Should I delete this post to raise a fresh post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I get it now: you have $y^2=x(x^2+z^4)$. What you can say is $x|y^2$ and $(x^2+z^4)|y^2$. You can't conlude that $y|x$ since that would mean $|y|\leq |x|$ but we already know that $|x|(x^2+z^4)=|y|^2\leq |x^2|$ which implies that $x^2+z^4\leq |x|$ since in your linked question you've taken $x,y,z \neq 0$. But this is trivially false as $x^2\geq |x|$ and $z^4\geq 1$ (since $z\neq0$).

If $p=\gcd(x,z)$, then $p^3|x(x^2+z^4)=y^2$. However, this doesn't imply $p^2|y$ since you have the counterexample $4^3|8^2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for making it obvious that $y\nmid x$. Regarding the implication $p^2\nmid y$, as stated by you, it is given in the proof: " If $p^3\mid y^2$, then certainly $p^2\mid y$, say $y=p^2Y$" (where $y=pY$). Sorry, again for typos in the OP in the powers of $p,y$. Now, no typo remains, I am sure about that totally.

Comment: Please respond to my earlier comment.

Comment: If $p^3|y^2$, then $p^2|y^2$, not $p^2|y$. The power of $y$ is important. There are counterexamples to $p^2|y$ as stated in my answer. You'll need other restrictions on $p$ to get to $p^2|y$

Comment: Please state which other restrictions can apply so as to enable the proof's implication : $p^3\mid y^2\implies p^2\mid y$ to be valid. As I stated  in the earlier comment to you that the proof states that :"$p^3\mid y^2\implies p^2\mid y$, say $y=p^2Y$ with $y=pY$".

Comment: For example: If all powers in the prime factorization of $p$ are odd

Comment: But such restriction is not imposed in the proof till 'this' line. It is a 30-40 line proof and the given line occurs in the very beginning only. If you need, I can repeat the whole proof which actually concerns the proof by contradiction(showing failure) of the earlier post, as specified in the link here.-----The proof states that : "Let $p$ be any prime dividing $\gcd(x,z)$. This means that $x=pX, z=pZ$. Substituting in the original equation" (i.e. to be proved to be failure by contradiction, as in the earlier post of mine) ", we get $Y^2= p^3(X^3 + p^2XZ^2) $. This means $p^3\mid y^2$

Comment: If $p$ is prime, then this implication holds indeed. Notice that the prime factorization of $p$  is just $p$ hence the only power (which is $1$) is odd.

Comment: Sorry, the last line is:" $y^2 = p^3(X^3+p^2XZ^4)$. This means $p^3\mid y^2$, so certainly $p^2\mid y$, say $y=p^2Y.$" There are still 15-18 more lines in the proof of the 'earlier' post.

Comment: Please give proof that: for odd powers (which $1$ is) of $p$ the implication holds true, i.e. "$p^3\mid y^2\implies p^2\mid y$, say $y=p^2Y$."

Comment: I am utterly clueless about the proof requested (by me) in my earlier comment, and feel it is out of my reach to get it.

Comment: $p^3|y^2 \implies p|y^2 \implies p|y   \implies y=pk$. Hence $p^3|y^2 \Leftrightarrow p^3| p^2k^2 \implies p|k^2 \implies p|k \implies p^2|pk=y^2$

Comment: Unable to understand your proof for the implication requested by me. I am unclear in the "first line" in following two issues. Why : (i) $p^3\mid  y^2\implies p\mid y^2$; (ii) $p\mid y^2\implies p\mid y$ as $p$ is prime. However, the second line is clear, as can understand by earlier knowledge that $p\mid k^2\implies p\mid k$. Also, there is a typo is in the very last portion, as there should be : $p^2\mid pk=y$ , instead.